# The function contains in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to do this:

```
for(i=0;i<$scope.users.length;i++){
    var name= $scope.users[i].name;

    if(!(name.contains('ext'))){
        $scope.users.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

But I have an error about function contains.
I tried match funtion too and I had the same problem.
Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Strings don't have a `.contains()` method.

Use:

```
if (name.indexOf('ext') === -1) {
    ...
}
```

ES6 has a `String.prototype.includes()` method, but this is currently only supported in Chrome and FireFox. You would be better off using the above approach for now.

Your loop there also isn't going to work because you are removing elements from the array while you are iterating through it. You would be better off doing:

```
$scope.users = $scope.users.filter(function (user) {
    return user.name.indexOf('ext') !== -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)?

Or you can try `name.indexOf('ext') === -1`